# New versions of docker packages are not available in the amazon-linux-extras

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-linux, amazon-linux-2

I have a requirement of updating the docker version to `19.03.11` or later on the amazonlinx2 and that package is not listed in the package list.

If I execute `amazon-linux-extras install docker=19.03.11` it won't be succeeded and says "Nothing to do"

But, if I just execute only `amazon-linux-extras install docker` it will install the version `19.03.13ce-1.amzn2` even a newer version than my expectation. The same way, If I specify the `amazon-linux-extras install docker=19.03.13` it says nothing to do.

What I noticed was amazon-linux-extras shows only this and these versions can be installed.

```
docker=latest            enabled      \
        [ =17.12.1  =18.03.1  =18.06.1  =18.09.9  =stable ]
```

Why I can see a newer version without specifying the image version and why I cannot install the required version on my amazonlinux2 server.

I really appreciate your valuable thoughts and ideas.

Comment: have you tried directly via `yum install docker` instead of amazon-linux-extras?

Comment: Hi Yes, already didn't work either. :(